# How to suppress blank wish window in tcl app wraped by freewrap

Tags: windows, tcl, exe, word-wrap

I use freewrap to wrap my tcl scripts to a windows exe file. I run this exe from a batch file and after the job is done, a blank Wish window remains. Is there a way to create a exe without showing the Wish window ?

Comment: Do your scripts (intentionally) use Tk at all? If not, there may be a way to tell freewrap to leave that part of things out. (Not that I know for sure, but it's the kind of thing I'd expect/look for…)

Comment: Yes, there's a Tcl-only version: freewrapTCLSH. It's probably better for OP because it doesn't detach from the command console / bat file. The regular (wish) version is for "double-click" applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of a script, wish doesn't automatically exit like tclsh does, it enters the event loop. Put an `exit` at the end of the script.

A wish script always has a top window, it just doesn't show until you enter the event loop or when an error is uncatched and reported. If you're not using it, start the script by hiding it with `wm withdraw .`.